# Entity добавляет к названию поля "1"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При добавлении миграции в таблицу дублируется поле (но в конце с `1`):

```
            CreateTable(
            "public.t_users",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    login = c.String(),
                    password = c.String(),
                    name = c.String(),
                    role_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    role_id1 = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
            .ForeignKey("public.t_roles", t => t.role_id1)
            .Index(t => t.role_id1);
```

Хотя в БД оно одно:

```
-- Table: public.t_users

-- DROP TABLE public.t_users;

CREATE TABLE public.t_users
(
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    login character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role_id integer NOT NULL,
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('t_users_id_seq'::regclass)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.t_users
    OWNER to psp;
```

Было бы хорошо, если оно было бы только при миграции...но это поле всплывает и при сохранении в БД...и естественно вылетает ошибка от `Entity`:

`BaseMessage = "column \"role_id1\" of relation \"t_users\" does not exist"`

model:

```
namespace Loyalty.DAL.Models.Authorize
{
    [Table("t_users", Schema = "public")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public int role_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Role role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста "как так", и зачем он (`Entity`) добавляет это поле?

Comment: Покажите вашу модель

Comment: а модель как выглядит?

Comment: @LLENN добавил модель

Comment: @tym32167 добавил модель

Comment: Уберите у ключа налейбл тип. Ну, а второе поле, это ссылка на id, вашего `role`. `.ForeignKey("public.t_roles", t => t.role_id1)`.

Comment: ну или аттрибут `[ForeignKey("role")] public int role_id { get; set; }`

Comment: и да, у вас `role_id` - тип `int`, что не допускает NULL, а чему оно должно быть равно, если юзер есть, а роли нет?

Comment: @tym32167 такого не может быть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно явно указать, что поле является [внешним коючем](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

```
[Table("t_users", Schema = "public")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(role))]
    public int role_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Role role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: (либо следовать соглашению об именовании)

Comment: @АндрейNOP то есть первому примеру по ссылке